# Integral Calculus involving Stokes Theorem

Tags: calculus

Show that the following problem does not admit a $C^{\infty}$ solution:

$\Delta u = x^2 - y^2 + z^2$ in $Q^3$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} (x,y,z) = 0$ in $\partial Q^3$

Comment: What is $Q^3$? What have you tried?

Comment: Hey. The definition is: $Q^3 = \{x = (x_1,...,x_k) : x_i \geq 0 , x_1+...+x_k \leq 1\}$. I am pretty sure there's a version of Stokes Theorem where you can plug $\partial u/\partial n$, but i cant find it here in my books. So then we could find an integral over $Q^3$ that is zero. Still trying to find the right formula